# LinearLayout and TextView doesn't show properly

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a new `LinearLayout` and now i have added a text and a background and now the background appears and still not full as it seems in the graphical they both show up in the graphical layout

**example here:**
https://www.dropbox.com/s/k58uznho9pu5qky/Untitled1.png

and when i test it out in a emulator which is real device the background isn't showing probably with some white space down and the text doesn't even appear

**example here:**
https://www.dropbox.com/s/q9e45sunbsesrd1/uniteled3.png

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/relLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="right"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".SecondActivity" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linearlayout2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/images"
                        android:gravity="center|right"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/two"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="10sp"
        android:text="testing ytestifnfndfijdfhffdkjdfkjfdjkj"
        android:textSize="25sp" />


</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: what is the need for scrollview?

Comment: Do you need that ScrollView? Do you want the background to fill the screen? Is the background proper 9 patch image?

Answer (score 0):

How does this fit your needs? If you plan to add more content, then the root component can be `ScrollView` with the background. But with only one `TextView`, there should be no need for `ScrollView` unless the text is huge.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:background="@drawable/images"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".SecondActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/two"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="testing ytestifnfndfijdfhffdkjdfkjfdjkj"
    android:textSize="25sp" />

</LinearLayout >
```

Answer (score 0):

to fill whole screen with your layout use match_parent for layout_height and layout_width

```
<LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearlayout2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/images"
                    android:gravity="center|right"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >
```